# Tornado log rotation for each day

Tags: python-2.7, logging, tornado, log-rotation

I am trying to log the requests to my tornado server to separate file, and I want to make a log rotation for each day. I want to use the tornado.log function and not the python logging.

I have defined the log path in my main class and it is logging properly I want to know if I can do a log rotate.

Does tornado log allow us to log things based on type like log4j

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado's logging just uses the python `logging` module directly; it's not a separate system. Tornado defines some command-line flags to configure logging in simple ways, but if you want anything else you can do it directly with the `logging` module. A timed rotation mode is being added in Tornado 4.3 (`--log-rotate-mode=time`), and until then you can use `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler`.

Comment: I am new to this logging, where should i use this TimedRotatingFileHandler, should i put it in the file with which i start the tornado server or i have to put it in all the files inside the application. Is it possible do a separate log based on type in tornado because I am connecting the tornado server with another server so if i get some error from the other server it is only logged as 200 ok in the log and i don get to see the error from that server.

Comment: See the [standard library's logging docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Configuring logging should be one of the first things you do in your main function. Tornado uses several loggers documented under the [tornado.log](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html) module.